# Black Screen , no command found in fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, command, gnome-terminal

When Starting Fedora linux after uninstalling / removing *Cinnamon Desktop Environment* I got login screen but after trying to log in I got *black screen* in Gnome and KDE .

After that I tried to go in *tty* and try to issue any command but , I got this *dnf command not found* , *ls command not found* message / error .

**SCREENSHOT**
[image: no command found fedora]

But When I was First Rebooted My PC after removing *Cinnamon Desktop Environment* , I just entered in Gnome , But only some 5-6 software like chrome  were available and software like settings , nautilus , terminal were not available . But now Gnome or any desktop environment is only showing the black screen .

And Currently Cinnamon Flavour is available, even after deleting it .

**SCREENSHOT**

[image: Cinnamon available after deleting it]

I browsed on internet but i didn't found solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your profile is busted. Login under root and create a new user account. Copy/move your old data from the old user to the new one.

If you don't remember root password reboot and add `init=/bin/bash` as a kernel command line argument, issue `passwd`, set a new root password, run `sync` and then `reboot`.

---

Alternatively, do this in a terminal (granted you're in your user directory - check using `pwd` - you should see something like `/home/username`):

```bsh
/bin/mkdir BACKUP
/bin/mv * .* BACKUP
/bin/cp -a /etc/skel/* .
```

Now you must be able to login into your graphical DEs.

Comment: Actually it was happend because I changed my profile , later on i just revert the changes that I did on my profile and everything was ok .